# Create address link from database row query

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink

I would like to ask if anyone have any useful tips for a problem I'm having.

I have table in my database that looks like this:

```
row_Id     unique_ID     Name     Info     Etc...
1          5004007       Alice    Doctor
2          6402305       Thomas   Actor
```

I am trying to have an address link that will look something like:

http://mywebsite/ppl/5004007 - site with this link would echo values from row #1
http://mywebsite/ppl/6402305 - would echo values from row #2

And so on.

Can anyone help me please?

---

Here what I have so far:

```
<?php
include "./connect.php";

$result = MySQL_DB_Query($ac_db,"SELECT artists_id_gg FROM ivgdb_artists WHERE artists_id_gg = 1001001");
//  $unique_link = MySQL_Num_Rows($result);

echo "<a target=\"_new\" href=\"mywebsite/ppl/"; . $result "\">This is the link to the page with that row's info.</a>";
?>
```

Shoud be something along the lines: ;
but with informations pulled from that table's row

Comment: `echo "/ppl/" . $unique_ID` presumably where that's a value you fetch from your database. What's the problem here? How far did you get with the code? It's hard to answer a problem when there's very little context given, especially the nature of your MySQL code.

Comment: If you want the link as shown, it will require some changes to your .htaccess file. It would be better if your link appears as shown in @Asim answer below

Comment: Please put your PHP code in the question itself.

Comment: Please don't post solutions within your question. Please first work at making your question on-topic and then having it reopened. Then you can post your solution as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change your link to like this :

http://mywebsite/ppl/unique_ID=5004007

you get a variable in php using this

```
$unique=$_GET["unique_ID"];
```

edit:

your link must be

http://mywebsite/ppl/?unique_ID=5004007

thanks -rtfm

Comment: `?unique_ID=5004007`

Comment: thanks ... i forget question mark

Comment: When you make an update, don't bother with putting "Edit:" into the Answer's text. Just update the answer with the correct information.